# How to not render a Panel Control as a <div>

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I use Asp.net 4 and C#.

I have a common web control `<asp:Panel>`. It is my understanding that if the Panel is visible it renders in the Browser as a `<div></div>` tag.

I would like to know if is possible to change this behavior and display the content of the Panel without rendering its `<div>`.

- Any idea how to do it?
- Can I use another control instead of Panel?

An example of code would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Simple :**

```
use PlaceHolder or  Literal
```

it renders only what it has - nothing more nothing less.

Comment: perfect I will accept your answer that solved my problem. Many thanks once again.

Comment: please notice that ive changed to PlaceHolder  and not contentPlaceHolder ( by mistake).

Answer (score 6):

If you use an ASP.NET `PlaceHolder` control then you will not get the div tags.

Of course if you use a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) you will not get a HTML element for this (i.e. a DIV tag) so you cannot set properties such as BackImageUrl or Wrap, etc. on the control.

Comment: @kgw - I did say that (in the first sentence). Can you re-read it and just double check, please?